# why this winform hangs and become unresponsive?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, azure, speech-to-text

I have this visual basic winform which converts speech to text. This winform has 1 button and one textbox and uses azure Speech to text service. When I click button , It converts speech to text and shows in textbox but the problem is, the winform starts hanging and i cant do anything else and not even able close the winform. Anyone know what is going wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Form1.vb**

```
   Imports Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SpeechContinuousRecognitionAsync().Wait()



    End Sub

    Public Async Function SpeechContinuousRecognitionAsync() As Task
        Dim config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("api key", "westus")

        Using recognizer = New SpeechRecognizer(config)

            AddHandler recognizer.SessionStarted, AddressOf recognizer_sessionstarted
            AddHandler recognizer.SessionStopped, AddressOf recognizer_sessionstopped
            AddHandler recognizer.Recognizing, AddressOf recognizer_Recognizing
            AddHandler recognizer.Recognized, AddressOf recognizer_Recognized
            AddHandler recognizer.Canceled, AddressOf recognizer_Canceled
            Await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(True)




        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub recognizer_sessionstarted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SessionEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("\n    Session started event.")


    End Sub
    Private Sub recognizer_sessionstopped(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SessionEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.")


    End Sub
    Private Sub recognizer_Recognizing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechRecognitionEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: Text={e.Result.Text}")


    End Sub
    Private Sub recognizer_Recognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechRecognitionEventArgs)
        TextBox1.Text = e.Result.Text


    End Sub
    Private Sub recognizer_Canceled(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine($"\n    Recognition Canceled. Reason: {e.Reason.ToString()}, CanceledReason: {e.Reason}")


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This: `SpeechContinuousRecognitionAsync().Wait()` is blocking. Make the Button.Click handler `async` and `await SpeechContinuousRecognitionAsync()`. Remove the `recognizer` handlers when done (after you have called `StopContinuousRecognitionAsync`, not shown here).

Comment: Remove `.ConfigureAwait(True)`. It's the default behavior (you're in a Context-full environment; you might need `ConfigureAwait(False)` in a Context-less one). You might also need to `BeginInvoke()` the UI Thread in the event handlers, if you're setting properties of Controls.

Comment: The tutorials shown here: [Recognize intents from speech using the Speech SDK for C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-intents-from-speech-csharp) might also be useful.

Comment: @Jimi I made the button_click async , configure wait(true) and await SpeechContinuousRecognition Async()   .  Now the winform is not hanging but nothing is showing in the textboxt1 and no event other than sessionstarted is generated

Comment: Follow the tutorial I linked.

Comment: if you change textbox1.text to Console.WriteLine you will see that it would output something, try invoking textbox1 cause you're probably working from another thread